# How to have CMake use the boost under /usr/local

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have boost 1.46 installed in /usr and 1.53 in /usr/local/. And I would like to link my binary to the latter one in CMake. Although I use

```
cmake . -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local
```

The result is weird:

```
Include dirs of boost: /usr/local/include
Libs of boost: /usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a
```

How can CMake find head files and libraries in completely different paths?

Comment: Can you please double-check that `libboost_program_options-mt.a` exists in the `/usr/local/lib` directory?

Answer (score 1):

Set additional variable with CMake

> cmake . -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=ON

This will force module to use search hint and skip additional system checks.

Also you can add -DBoost_DEBUG=ON to enable debug output regarding search process.

Answer (score 0):

You can define BOOST_ROOT enviromental variable pointing to your boost directory:

```
BOOST_ROOT=/usr/local
```